# When passing through void pointer values changing and getting segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable, void-pointers

**Background**: Creating a hash table library which allows 3 different implementations 2 which solve collisions with open addressing (one being of fixed size and the other dynamic) and a 3rd which uses separate chaining with linked lists.

**Background to the Problem**: Started by creating the fixed size open addressing. At first this worked perfectly, however, had to make some changes to to adapt the library to cater for the other two implementations. For this I needed to record the size of the list (used structures) and void pointers as structures for the open addressing and separate chaining are different.

**The Actual Problem**: For some reason my save function is no longer working while debugging I've noticed two issues which I cannot discern the cause of:

1. passing a structure through a void pointer to this function the
   values change (please note that this only happens in this functions
   and while I uses the same method in the rest of the functions I do
   not get the same problem)
2. I get a segmentation fault on an fprintf statement (that previous to the above mentioned amendments was working.

**The Save Function in Question**:

```
    void hashtbl_savetofile(void* hashtbl, const char *path){
        Hashtbl *temp;
        temp = hashtbl;
        int i;

        FILE *f = fopen(path, "w");

        if (f == NULL){
            printf("FILE NOT FOUND!");
        }else {
            for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
                fprintf(f, "%s", temp->data[i].subscript); // segmentation fault occurs
                fprintf(f, "%s", temp->data[i].value);
            }
            fclose(f);
            free(temp);
        }
    }
```

**The Header File**:

```
    #ifndef TASK2_HASHTABLE_H
    #define TASK2_HASHTABLE_H

    #define SIZE 20
    #define MAX_LENGTH 100
    #define INIT_SIZE 64000

    typedef struct Data_struct{
        char *subscript;
        char *value;
    } Data;

    typedef struct Hashtbls{
        int numberOfEntries;
        int allocatedEntries;
        Data *data;
    }Hashtbl;

    int hashtbl_hashKey(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript ); // generates hash key for hash table
    Data hashtbl_lookup(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript); //looks up and retrieves a given subscript and its value hash table
    void* hashtbl_insert(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript, const char *value); //adds a given subscript and its value to hash table
    void* hashtbl_delete(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript); //deletes a given subscript and its value from hash table
    void hashtbl_savetofile(void* hashtbl, const char *path); //saves hash table to file
    void* hashtbl_loadfromfile(void* hashtbl, const char *path); //loads hash table from file
    void* hashtbl_init();

    #endif //TASK2_HASHTABLE_H
```

**The Test Driver**:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "hashtable.h"

    int main() {
        Hashtbl *nums;
        Data d;
        nums = hashtbl_init();
        hashtbl_insert(nums, "tea", "40c");
        hashtbl_insert(nums, "coffee", "50c");
        hashtbl_insert(nums, "biscuit", "4c");
        hashtbl_insert(nums, "tart", "30c");
        d = hashtbl_lookup(nums, "tart");
        printf("%s", d.subscript);
        printf("%s", d.value);
        hashtbl_savetofile(nums, "test.txt");
    }
```

**The Implementation** (for reference):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "hashtable.h"

    void* hashtbl_init(){ //initiates static 2D hash table when called
        Hashtbl* hashtbl;
        hashtbl = malloc(INIT_SIZE);
        hashtbl->numberOfEntries = SIZE;
        hashtbl->allocatedEntries = 0;
        hashtbl->data = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(Data));
        for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
            hashtbl->data[i].subscript = malloc(MAX_LENGTH + 1);
            strcpy(hashtbl->data[i].subscript, "ZERO\n");

            hashtbl->data[i].value = malloc(MAX_LENGTH + 1);
            strcpy(hashtbl->data[i].value, "ZERO\n");
        }
        return hashtbl;
    }

    Data hashtbl_lookup(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript){
        Data item;
        Hashtbl *temp;
        temp = hashtbl;
        int i = 0;
        char *c;
        c = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
        strcpy(c, subscript);
        strct(c, "\n");

        while (strcmp(temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i)].subscript, c) != 0){
            i++;
            if(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i == temp->numberOfEntries){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i != temp->numberOfEntries) {
            if(strcmp(temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i)].subscript, c) == 0) {
                item.subscript = temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i)].subscript;
                item.value = temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i)].value;
            }
        }else{
            for(i = 0; i<hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript); i++){
                if(strcmp(temp->data[i].subscript, c) == 0){
                    item.subscript = temp->data[i].subscript;
                    item.value = temp->data[i].value;
                }
            }
        }
        free(hashtbl);
        free(c);
        free(temp);

       return item;//what if not found
    }

    void* hashtbl_insert(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript, const char *value){
        Hashtbl *temp;
        temp = hashtbl;
        int i = 0;
        char *c1;
        c1 = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
        strcpy(c1, subscript);
        strcat(c1, "\n");
        char *c2;
        c2 = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
        strcpy(c2, value);
        strcat(c2, "\n");

        if(temp->allocatedEntries == temp->numberOfEntries){
            free(c1);
            free(c2);
            free(temp);
            return hashtbl;
        }else {
            if (strcmp(temp->data[hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i].subscript, "ZERO\n") == 0) {
                temp->data[hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)].subscript = c1;
                temp->data[hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)].value = c2;
                temp->allocatedEntries++;
            } else {
                while ((strcmp(temp->data[hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i].subscript, "ZERO\n") != 0)) {
                    i++;
                    if (hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i == temp->numberOfEntries) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i != temp->numberOfEntries) {
                    if ((strcmp(temp->data[hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i].subscript, "ZERO\n") == 0)) {
                        temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i)].subscript = c1;
                        temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i)].value = c2;
                        temp->allocatedEntries++;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (i = 0; i < hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript); i++) {
                        if (strcmp(temp->data[i].subscript, "ZERO\n") == 0) {
                            temp->data[i].subscript = c1;
                            temp->data[i].value = c2;
                            temp->allocatedEntries++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            free(c1);
            free(c2);

            return temp;
        }
    }

    void* hashtbl_delete(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript){
        Hashtbl *temp;
        temp = hashtbl;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char *c;
        c = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
        strcpy(c, subscript);
        strcat(c, "\n");

        while ((strcmp(temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i)].subscript, c) != 0)){
            i++;
            if((hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i) == temp->numberOfEntries) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i != temp->numberOfEntries) {
            if(strcmp(temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript)+i)].subscript, c) == 0) {
                temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i)].subscript = "ZERO\n";
                temp->data[(hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript) + i)].value = "ZERO\n";
                temp->allocatedEntries--;
            }
        }else{
            for(j = 0; j<hashtbl_hashKey(hashtbl, subscript); j++){
                if(strcmp(temp->data[j].subscript, c) == 0){
                    temp->data[j].subscript = "ZERO\n";
                    temp->data[j].value = "ZERO\n";
                    temp->allocatedEntries--;
                }
            }
        }
        hashtbl=temp;
        free(c);
        free(temp);
        return hashtbl;
    }

    void hashtbl_savetofile(void* hashtbl, const char *path){
        //provided above
    }

    void* hashtbl_loadfromfile(void* hashtbl, const char *path){
        Hashtbl *temp;
        temp = hashtbl;
        temp->allocatedEntries=0;
        int i = 0;
        int j =0;
        int c = 0;
        char line[100];
        char* string[temp->numberOfEntries];

        FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");

        if(f == NULL){
            free(temp);
            return NULL;
        }else {
            while(fgets(line, sizeof line, f)){
                j++;
            }
            if((j/2)>temp->numberOfEntries){
                free(temp);
                return NULL;
            }else {
                while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) {
                    string[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
                    if (string[i] == NULL) {
                        break;
                        return NULL;
                    } else {
                        strcpy(string[i], line);
                        i++;
                        if (i == sizeof string / sizeof *string) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                fclose(f);

                for (i = 0; i < (SIZE * 2); i++) {
                    if (strlen(string[i]) >= MAX_LENGTH) {
                        char *k = realloc(temp->data[c].subscript, strlen(string[i]));
                        if (k == NULL) {
                            break;
                            return NULL;
                        } else {
                            temp->data[c].subscript = k;
                            strcpy(temp->data[c].subscript, string[i]);
                            if(temp->data[c].subscript != "ZERO\n"){
                                temp->allocatedEntries++;
                            }
                            i++;
                            c++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        temp->data[c].subscript = malloc(strlen(string[i]) + 1);
                        strcpy(temp->data[c].subscript, string[i]);
                        if(temp->data[c].subscript != "ZERO\n"){
                            temp->allocatedEntries++;
                        }
                        i++;
                        c++;
                    }
                }
                c = 0;
                for (i = 1; i < (SIZE * 2); i++) {
                    if (strlen(string[i]) >= MAX_LENGTH) {
                        char *k = realloc(temp->data[c].value, strlen(string[i]));
                        if (k == NULL) {
                            break;
                            return NULL;
                        } else {
                            temp->data[c].value = k;
                            strcpy(temp->data[c].value, string[i]);
                            i++;
                            c++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        temp->data[c].value = malloc(strlen(string[i]) + 1);
                        strcpy(temp->data[c].value, string[i]);
                        i++;
                        c++;
                    }
                }
                hashtbl=temp;
                free(temp);
                free(string);
                return hashtbl;
            }
        }
    }

    int hashtbl_hashKey(void* hashtbl, const char *subscript){
        int i;
        int h = 0;

        for(i = 0; subscript[i]; i++){
            h += subscript[i];
        }
        h = h%SIZE;
        return h;
    }
```

Comment: If you get an segfault with `fprintf(f, "%s"...`, then it could mean two things: the pointer points to `NULL` or your string is **not** a C-String, meaning that it doesn't have a `\0` terminating byte. That's a lot of code to review, if you are using a debugger, add a breakpoint before the `fprintf` and inspect `temp->data[i].subscript`. Does the string have a `\0` byte?

Comment: Also, in `hashtbl_lookup`, allocate `c` like this `c = malloc(MAX_LENGTH+1);` to ensure that you also save the `\0` terminating byte (like you do in `hashtbl_init`.

Comment: Without reading all of the code, the `free(temp);` in `hashtbl_savetofile()` worries me: You are freeing something that was passed in to you. That is dangerous! In the real world you don't even know it was dynamically allocated. I'm guessing that you still use it after it was freed (just a guess, like I said - too much code for me to check it all)'

Comment: are the `"40c"`, `"50c"`, `"4c"` hex representations of numbers or  are they random strings that here happen to look like hex representation? Because if you are storing hex representations, it would make your code much easier if you store a `uint32_t`/`uint64_t` instead and only convert to hex representation when needed.

Comment: @John3136 I wasn't considering that it could be used mid-use sort of always pictured it being used at the end - which in itself is a mistake

Comment: @Pablo re 40c they're random strings ( c as in cents)

Comment: @Pablo with regards to the `fprintf(...` is it possible that gets nulled when being passed through the parameter as, while i can't check  if `temp->data[i].subscript` becomes `NULL` or if it retains '\0` byte at the end, when inspecting `temp->numberOfEntries` which should be set at `20`, when entering `savetofile()` it becomes a random number?

Comment: @JohnParnis I don't get what you are trying to say. No string gets changed because you've passed it as a parameter. While filling the data, it's your job that the data to ensure that the data is valid, in case of strings, that **all** strings have a terminating 0 byte, that the buffers have enough space, etc, specially when reading from a file or user.

Comment: solved it the problem was a `free(temp)` statement in `hashtbl_looip'

Comment: regarding: `void* hashtbl_init();`  When writing a prototype for a function that takes no parameters, place `void` between the parens

Comment: regarding: `strct(c, "\n");`  This does not compile!!!

Comment: there are some comparisons between signed and unsigned integer expressions.  This needs to be corrected.

Comment: regarding: `if(temp->data[c].subscript != "ZERO\n"){`  and `if(temp->data[c].subscript != "ZERO\n"){`  These are comparing comparing pointers, NOT the strings.  Suggest using `strcmp()`

Comment: in function: `hashtbl_haskKey()`,  the parameter: `hashtbl` is not used, so either redesign the code to not contain that parameter (prefered) or the first line in the body of the function should be: `(void)hashtbl;`

Comment: regarding: ` while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f)) {`  this will place the trailing newline character into the input buffer: `line[]`.  You probably do not want to include that trailing newline in the following calculations.  so suggest: `char *newline = NULL;  if( (newline = strchr( line, '\n' )) != NULL ) { *newline = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `if (string[i] == NULL) {
                        break;
                        return NULL;`  the 'break;' statement will immediately exit the `while()` loop, so the statement: `return NULL;` will never be executed.  Probably should have called 'perror()` before the `break` statement to output an error message onto `stderr`, indicating a failure occurred

Comment: regarding: `if (i == sizeof string / sizeof *string) {`  the variable `string` has a size of a pointer times `temp->numberOfEntries`  The first entry in `string` '*string'` is also a pointer with a size of 4 bytes.   so, maybe, the `break` will be executed when `i` is equal to temp->numberOfEntries`  However, the operator `sizeof` returns a compile time value, not a run time value and the code is comparing that (unsigned) value to `i` which is an `int`  LOTS of problems with that statement.

Comment: in function: `hashtbl_savetofile()`, the parameter `path` is unused.  Suggest rewriting that code to not have that parameter or the first statement in the body of the function should be: `(void)path;`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: for ease of readability and undestanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default ) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)   Treat the closing brace '}' as the end of a statement

Comment: regarding: `free(string);`  Before passing `string` to `free()`, each of the allocated pointers within `string` must be passed to `free()`.  Do not force the OS to clean up after sloppy code, as that will, especially on embedded systems, burn you.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `if(temp->allocatedEntries == temp->numberOfEntries){
            free(c1);
            free(c2);
            free(temp);
            return hashtbl;` the call to `free(temp)` is freeing the callers' hashtable (without even freeing all the allocated memory entries within that table)  Suggest removing that call to `free()`

Comment: @user3629249 regarding strcat(c, "\n") i checked again observing it in the debugger and it works \n is appended to the end of c

Comment: The posted code has: `strct(c, "\n");` I.E. STRCT` not `STRCAT`